# How to disable scroll bars in 100vh in split screens?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, primeng

This is my login form. I am using prime ng. I am using 100vh for the full height. I use flex for display vertically and horizontally centered contents. I give 100% height for each column. The problem is that the horizontal and vertical scroll bar appears when typing. I want to hide the scroll bars.

```
<div class="p-grid" style="height: 100vh">
  <div class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-6 p-lg-6" style="height: 100%">    
    <h4>Logo</h4>
  </div>

  <div
    class="p-col-12 p-sm-12 p-md-6 p-lg-6"
    style="background-color: #f1f1f2; height: 100%"
  >
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <h4>LOGIN</h4>

        <!--Phone Starts-->

        <div>
          <p>Phone</p>

          <input type="email" formControlName="phone" size="50" pInputText />
        </div>

        <p-message
          severity="error"
          text="Phone no. is required"
          *ngIf="loginForm.get('phone').errors?.required && formSubmitted"
        ></p-message>

        <p-message
          severity="error"
          text="Please enter valid phone no."
          *ngIf="loginForm.get('phone').errors?.pattern && formSubmitted"
        ></p-message>

        <!--Phone Ends-->

        <div class="p-mt-3"></div>

        <!--Password Starts-->

        <div>
          <p>Password</p>

          <input
            type="password"
            formControlName="password"
            size="50"
            pInputText
          />
        </div>

        <p-message
          severity="error"
          text="Password is required"
          *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').errors?.required && formSubmitted"
        ></p-message>

        <p-message
          severity="error"
          text="Please enter a password with 6 characters"
          *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').errors?.minlength && formSubmitted"
        ></p-message>

        <!--Password Ends-->

        <div class="p-mt-3"></div>

        <p-button
          label="Login"
          styleClass="ui-button-success"
          (click)="onSubmit()"
        ></p-button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.p-col-12,
.p-sm-12,
.p-md-6,
.p-lg-6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

When typing in the form the scroll bar appears and disappears.

[image]

Comment: why are you mixing vh and %. Stick to one of those and check

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow-x: hidden;` on your div to resolve the issue.

If you want to hide vertical as well, use: `overflow-y: hidden;`

And also don't mix between `vh` and `%`. Decide on one and stick with it.

**Short story**

```
.p-grid{
    overflow-x: hidden; //Horizontal
    overflow-y: hidden; //Vertical
}
```